# Script Outcome > Textfile

Tags: text, powershell, export

I have the following two scripts. I would like to have a Text file created with the results in either

a)the same directory were the orginal execution took place     or

b)On the c: directory

1)

```
$sum = 0 
foreach ($i in dir -filter *.log -Rec)
{
$sum += (gc $i.fullname | select -Skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" | ? {$_.Details -match "^(\d+)"} |% {$matches[1]} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum
 }
$sum
[Console]::Write("Press any key to continue . . . ")
[Console]::ReadKey()
```

---

2)

```
 foreach ($i in dir -filter *.log -Rec)
 {
 $cameras = gc $i.fullname | select -Skip 5 | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "`t" | group "Entity "
 $cameras | select Name, @{n="Total";e={ ($_.group | ? {$_.Details -match "^(\d+)"} |% {$matches     [1]} | Measure-Object -Sum).Sum}} | ? {$_.Total -gt 0}
 }

 [Console]::Write("Press any key to continue . . . ")
 [Console]::ReadKey()
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing @Chris Browne says is that you can use CmdLet Out-File

The thing I add is for getting script exécution directory :

```
$scriptPath = Split-Path -Parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path;
$textFileName = $scriptPath + "\yourfile.txt"
$sum | out-file -FilePath $textFileName
```

Comment: So can you show me how to incoorporate this in the above two scripts?

Comment: you could use that as is, just do it after the foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cmdlet you're looking for is called Out-File.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx

Comment: Chris, can you show me how to add the comand line to the script?

Comment: You have to assign the result of the loop to a variable then pipe that to Out-File as in the below example:
(apologies for the poor formatting, I'm not used to stackex yet)
$NumArray = (1..12)
$(foreach ($number in $NumArray ) { $number * 7}) | set-variable 7x
$7x
# Option research properties by removing # on the next line
# $7x |Out-File

Comment: That's ok.  Put your entire foreach in () then add a pipe at the end to "set-variable output" then simply pipe "$output | Out-File C:/whatever.txt".  Apparently you can't pipe the foreach directly to Out-File but I haven't tried it so YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe $sum or $cameras to the Out-File cmdlet. To create the file in the current directory pass just the name of the file. To create it in the C: drive pass the full path:

```
$sum | Out-File -Path Results.txt

or 

$sum | Out-File -Path .\Results.txt

or:

$sum | Out-File -Path C:\Results.txt
```

By the way, you can write messages to the console by using the Write-Host cmdlet (instead of [Console]::Write, and wait for a key press with the Read-Host cmdlet (instead [Console]::ReadKey).